# Display Custom Embded TimeCode instead of Standard Timecode

Tags: video.js

I have video that uses different timecode tracks when we export our QT's.  Is there a way to make that timecode get displayed? It always is a 00:00:00:00 formatted number.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FDgF.png

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 video does not report frame information, so you would have to implement this yourself based on the current time & frame rate of the current video clip. There are a lot of pitfalls here if you are supporting a lot of different frame rates, so you'll have to do your calculations correctly in either a javascript timer or the HTML5 time updated event. If you want, you could then display the timecode over the video by absolutely positioning a div over the video element.